# Mi consola no muestra nada al ejecutar mis programas de sockets ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Buenas soy un programador novato y estoy aprendiendo python como nuevo lenguaje de programación, un proyecto que vi por ahi fue que usando sockets poder hacer lo siguiente:

1. Tomar un archivo del lado del servidor.
2. Comprimir el archivo a `.zip`.
3. Enviarlo.
4. El cliente lo recibe.
5. Se descomprime.
6. Obtener el archivo descomprimido.

Es decir enviar un archivo que se comprimió antes, hacia el cliente y este se descomprima al llegar.

En mi carpeta (donde tengo el código), tengo lo siguiente:

- Archivo llamado `LinkWarrior.jpg`
- Script `server.py`
- Script client. py
- Dos carpetas llamadas "servidor" y "cliente", para así simular el lado del cliente y del servidor.

**Mi problema es que la consola no me muestra nada cuando los ejecuto**, pareciera que se quedara en un ciclo o algo así, la cierro por si acaso me afecte la memoria.

Probé ambos programas, pero al ejecutarlos en la terminal del sistema se queda la consola como esperando. No sé si queda en un loop o algo porque al momento de entrar en un ciclo `while true` que tengo debería mostrar que se estableció la conexión al localhost con el puerto 8000, pero esto no sale. No sé que podría ser, si lo ejecuta comprime y descomprime bien solo que en la carpeta donde esté el código.

Estos son los programas que tengo:

### `Server.py`

```
import socket 
import os               #hacer zip a un archivo
import zipfile

def empaque ( path,zipActual ) :
    zipActual.write('LinkWarrior.jpg')

def main ():
    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('Prueba.zip','w') #creo el paquete
    empaque(os.getcwd(),myzip)
    myzip.close()
    
    mi_socket = socket.socket()
    mi_socket.bind( ('localhost',8000) )        #creo la conexion
    mi_socket.listen(5)
     

    if os.path.exists("servidor") == True:          #compruebo que existe carpeta
        ruta= os.getcwd()+"\servidor"
        if len(os.listdir(ruta))== 0:             #compruebo si esta vacia
            print("carpeta vacia")
        else:

            while True:
                conexion,addr = mi_socket.accept() 
                print ("Nueva conexión establecida")
                print (addr)

                file = open ("Prueba.zip","rb")
                content = file.read (1024)

                while True:
                    conexion.send(content)      #envio contenido
                    content = file.read (1024)
                    conexion.send("descarga completa")
                break

            conexion.close()
            file.close()
            print ("El archivo se ha enviado exitosamente")

    else:
        print("Crapeta servidor no existe, cree la carpeta y llamela 'servidor' ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### `Client.py`

```
import socket 
import os               #hacer zip a un archivo
import zipfile

def main ():
    mi_socket = socket.socket()
    mi_socket.bind( ('localhost',8000) )
    mi_socket.listen(5)
 
    
    if os.path.exists("cliente")==True:             #compruebo que existe carpeta
        ruta= os.getcwd()+"\cliente"
        if len(os.listdir(ruta))== 0:               #compruebo si esta vacia
            print("carpeta vacia")
        else:
            while True: 
                conexion,addr = mi_socket.accept()
                conexion.send("cliente conectado")

                file = open ('Prueba.zip','r')
                input_data =conexion.recv(1024)
                file.write (input_data)
                conexion.send ("archivo descargado por el cliente")
                break

        with zipfile.ZipFile('Prueba.zip','r') as myzip:        #descomprimo el archivo ZIP
            myzip.extractall()

        conexion.close()
        file.close()
        print ("El archivo se ha descargado exitosamente")
    else:
        print("Crapeta servidor no cliente, cree la carpeta y llamela 'servidor' ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: No queda claro cual es tu pregunta. Cuando creas un socket, se establece una conexión a la espera de señal del servidor. Entonces sí, se trata de un loop. Esto no te va a dañar la memoria ni nada xD. Te recomiendo que en una terminal ejecutes `server.py` y en otra `client.py`, si tu código está bien verás que si tiene efecto. Al final de esto se trata, que el cliente se comunique con el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Vas a tener que reenfocar tu programa.

Por el momento: ambos programas no pueden funcionar en la misma máquina, ya ambos hacen intentan hacer `bind` del mismo puerto 8000.

En aplicaciones de este tipo, el programa cliente es de este estilo:

```
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('servidor', 8000))
clientsocket.send('hello')
```

Las diferencias:

El cliente no hace `bind`. Al cliente no le interesa como se hace la conexión de su lado. No le interesa con que IP:puerta o por cual interfaz sale.

El cliente desea una conexión a un servidor. Eso lo hace con `connect`, indicando cual es el nombre/IP del servidor y a que puerto conectarse.

Una vez establecida la conexión, está en condiciones de enviar usando `send` y leer usando `recv`.

Aqui hay un ejemplo completo de un programa cliente:

```
import socket

def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()  # Cliente y servidor en el mismo PC.
    port = 8000  # Puerta del servidor

    client_socket = socket.socket()  # Instanciar un socket cliente
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # Conectarse al servidor

    message = input(">")  

    while message.lower().strip() != 'quit':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # Enviar mensaje
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # Recibir respuesta

        print('Received from server: ' + data)  # Desplegar

        message = input(">")  

    client_socket.close()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Este cliente lee una línea del teclado y la manda al servidor. Luego espera una respuesta, la imprime y repite el ciclo, hasta que el usuario escribe "quit".